# Check if a String List contains non-printable characters

Tags: c#, linq

using LINQ how can I check if any character in the string list contains non-printable characters

```
private bool CheckValidChars(List<string> inputList)
 {
   foreach(string s in inputList)
   {
     // Check each string for no printable chars ( 0x00 <= ch < 0x20 ) 
     // LINQ statment

   }
}
```

Comment: bool nonPrintable = s.Any(x => (byte)x < 0x20);

Comment: @jdweng I think that cast is redundant.

Comment: It is not a character array is not bytes.

Comment: @jdweng What I meant is that you can use `s.Any(x => x < 0x20)`. No cast is needed because the comparison between a char and an int is valid.

Comment: Remember that non-prinatable Chars are not only those under 0x20, because string defaults to unicode and might contain a variety of other chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title of your question implies that you want a method that returns `true` if  there are any invalid characters, but the method seems to want to return `true` if there are none. I'll assume the latter.

The easy way to do this is to fail early as soon as an invalid character is found and then flip the value with a `!`. In a completely valid list it will need to traverse the whole list and each character to determine validity, but if the list is invalid then this code will stop when it finds the first character in the first string that is invalid.

Here's the code:

```
private bool CheckValidChars(List<string> inputList) =>
    !inputList.Any(s => s.Any(c => c < 0x20));
```

Comment: As Boldar pointed out in a comment to the question, there are more unpribtable characters than just the range \U0000 to \U001F. If these shall also be recognized, replace `c => c < 0x20` by `c => char.IsControl(c)`.